# Covariant Derivatives and Swapping Indices

Tags: tensors

Okay,there's a covariant derivative of a rank 2 tensor. Swapping any indices gives a different tensor. Can we associate any physical significance to the swapping?

For example, if I have a velocity vector $u$$_i$ and its covariant derivative is $u$$_i,_j$ , will swappinng indices $i$ and $j$ have any consequences on say, the direction of the resulting tensor( Covariant derivative of the velocity vector is a tensor)?

Comment: at first, the covariant derivative is obtained at a point $x \in M$ from a direction (a vector of $T_xM$) and a vector field and yields a vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we have the covariant derivative in the $k$ direction for a rank one tensors, contravariantly
$$u^i{}_{;k}=u^i{,k}+\Gamma^i{}_{sk}u^s,$$
and covariantly
$$u_{i;k}=u_{i,k}-\Gamma^s{}_{ik}u_s,$$
which indicate a the tensor varies in direction $k$.

Then for rank two tensor we have the possibilities
$$A_{ij}\ ,\ A^i{}_j\ ,\ A^{ij}\ ,\ A_iB_j\ ,\ A^iB_j\ ,\ A^iB^j.$$

Then, for example 
$$A_{ij;k}=A_{ij,k}+\Gamma^s{}_{ik}A_{sj}+\Gamma^s{}_{jk}A_{is},$$
or
$$(A_iB_j)_{;k}=(A_iB_j)_{,k}+\Gamma^s{}_{ik}A_sB_j+\Gamma^s{}_{jk}A_iB_s,$$
tell you how tensor $A_{ij}$ or $A_iB_j%$ vary in direction $k$.